# How to upload image to server with Retrofit on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

In my application I should upload image to server.
For server requests I used **retrofit 2**
I write upload codes, but show me error for **validation and say me media field is empty**.

Upload image request from **PostMan** : [Click to see image](https://i.ibb.co/4g5mWJD/5.png)

In postman everything is ok and not any problem and image upload successfully!

But in my code show me validation error!

**My api interface code :**

```
@Multipart
@POST("media/")
fun uploadImage(
    @Header(AUTHORIZATION) auth: String, @Header(ACCEPT) accept: String, @Header(CONTENT_TYPE) contentType: String,
    @Part media: MultipartBody.Part
): Single<Response<ResponseModelUploadImage>>
```

**Upload image code :**

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    photoEasy.onActivityResult(
        requestCode, resultCode
    ) { thumbnail ->
        val imgFile = bitmapToFile(thumbnail, "myImageNameIsThisTest.jpeg")
        Log.e("filePath",imgFile.toString())
        val reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), imgFile)
        val filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("media", imgFile?.name, reqFile)

        presenter.callUploadImage(userToken, APPLICATION_JSON, APPLICATION_JSON, filePart)
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

[URL](https://nouri.in/courses/%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87-%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B9-constraintlayout-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D9%87%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%87-%D9%BE%D8%B1%D9%88%DA%98%D9%87-%D8%B9%D9%85%D9%84%DB%8C/)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of an upload function in an Android app (in Kotlin) that sends a picture to a server (in this case is a web application developed with Java and Spring Boot) with Retrofit as ***multipart/form-data***:

```
 private suspend fun sendPicture(sessionId: UUID, p: Picture): Boolean {

        try {
            val data_part = p.data.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
            val data_multi_part =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", p.description, data_part)
            val sessionId_part =
                sessionId.toString().toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
            val id_part = p.id.toString().toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
            val categoryId_part =
                p.categoryId?.toString()?.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
            val response = api.sendPicture(sessionId_part, id_part, categoryId_part, data_multi_part)
            if (!response.isSuccessful) {

                @Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")
                val msg = response.errorBody()?.string() ?: textHelper(
                    R.string.error_send_picture,
                    p.id.toString()
                )
                Logger.trace(EventCode.SerializationError, msg, EventSeverity.Error)
            }
            return response.isSuccessful

        } catch (e: Exception) {

            Logger.trace(p, EventCode.SerializationError, e.localizedMessage, Action.Send, EventSeverity.Exception)
        }

        return false
    }
```

And the generated API that uses Retrofit 2.6 is declared as follows:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("SendPicture")
    suspend fun sendPicture(@Part("sessionId") sessionId: RequestBody, @Part("pictureId") id: RequestBody, @Part("categoryId") categoryId: RequestBody?, @Part picture: MultipartBody.Part): Response<Void>
```

Take into account that `Picture` is an Android Room (ORM) entity and `p.data` it's the image representation as a byte array (`val data: ByteArray`).

```
sessionId = is a session ID (it's just a custom value of type UUID)
pictureId = is the ID of the picture (type: UUID)
categoryId = is the ID of the category the picture belongs to (type: UUID)
```

These 3 values are custom (you don't need them), they are there just to show how to pass more data to the server together with the image.

The function is written in Kotlin.

I think you have everything you need to extract the code that better suits your needs. This example is taken from the code of a project of mine and it was tested. It sends pictures stored in the local database to the server.

You can easily port the code to Java.